# unable to connect to Postgres Facing an error psql: error: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.x.x.x", user "user", database "db"

Tags: postgresql, openvpn

Hi I am trying to connect to postgres database but while connecting to it I am getting an error as

```
psql: error: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.x.x.x", user "user", database "db"
```

What I have tried
I tried configuring the pg_hba.conf file I am using a open vpn to connect and I have made these changes in pg_hba.conf file in attached screenshot below.

[image]

I am running this below command from cmd prompt

```
psql -h hostaddress -p 5432 -U username -d databasename
```

Comment: Are `x` and `*` the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The address entries in your pg_hba.conf are invalid. An address entry should look like this (there are no * placeholders in the IP address):

`host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5`

For your VPN subnet (assuming a class A private network and a subnet mask of 255.0.0.0) the entry should look like this:

`host all all 10.0.0.0/8 md5`

See also the the samples in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) of pg_hba.conf.